# how to pass 2 files in intent android

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to share 2 csv files I created in my app.
I was able to share one of them with the below code, but how to I pass 2 files to share?

```
  for (File file : fileList) {

                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        Toast.makeText(ExcelExportActivity.this, "File doesn't exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ExcelExportActivity.this, "com.example.farmers.provider", file);

                    grantUriPermission(ExcelExportActivity.this.getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    sharingIntent.setType("text/csv");
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);


                }
sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my subject");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "sharing with..."));
```

Comment: Create a ZIP file containing your two files, then share the ZIP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use **Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE** instead of Intent.ACTION_SEND.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here are some files.");
intent.setType("text/csv");

ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();

for(String path : filesToSend /* List of the files you want to send */) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    files.add(uri);
}

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
startActivity(intent);
```